# Elasticsearch 6.2.0 with python error

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I instal elasticsearch 6.2.0 with kibana in my mac when i am connect to kibana i can (get, post, put, delete) data witout problem but when a try this to my program a have a bug

> raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
>   elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(406, 'Content-Type header [] is not supported')

i use a default library elestic for python

this is my requirement file

```
certifi==2018.1.18
elasticsearch==1.9.0
numpy==1.13.1
opencv-python==3.3.0.10
simplejson==3.13.2
sip==4.19.3
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.22
```

in my .py file i have this

```
   from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
   es = Elasticsearch()
   es.index(index="my-index", doc_type="test-type", id=42, body={"any": "data", "timestamp": datetime.now()})
```

exactly as in the documentation

i find in the elastic github response for js but not for python

i try to put ssl but is not work

Comment: Version 1.9.0 seems like a very old release, you should upgrade to 6.1.1 (the latest). ES 6.2.0 came out yesterday, so you better use a recent version of the python client.

Comment: thx i did not no that i did not have a old release i have install 6.1.1 in now it work